# SQL - First row inserted every day for the past X days

Tags: sql, database, timestamp

A tough SQL question (I'm using postgres by the way).

I need the first row inserted every day for the past X days.  one of my columns is a timestamp, which i hold the time inserted, and another column is the row id.

If it's not possible to get the first row inserted every day, i at least need a unique one; a single row for every day for the past x days.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

okie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to try something like the following (tested in MySQL, but I guess it should be easy to port to  Postgres):

```
SELECT      l.id, l.timestamp, l.value
FROM        log l
INNER JOIN  (
             SELECT    MIN(timestamp) first_timestamp
             FROM      log
             GROUP BY  DATE(timestamp)
            ) sub_l ON (sub_l.first_timestamp = l.timestamp)
WHERE       l.timestamp > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 DAY);
```

Note that this assumes that your timestamps are unique.

Test Case (in MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE log (id int, timestamp datetime, value int);

INSERT INTO log VALUES (1, '2010-06-01 02:00:00', 100);
INSERT INTO log VALUES (2, '2010-06-01 03:00:00', 200);
INSERT INTO log VALUES (3, '2010-06-01 04:00:00', 300);
INSERT INTO log VALUES (4, '2010-06-02 02:00:00', 400);
INSERT INTO log VALUES (5, '2010-06-02 03:00:00', 500);
INSERT INTO log VALUES (6, '2010-06-03 02:00:00', 600);
INSERT INTO log VALUES (7, '2010-06-04 02:00:00', 700);
INSERT INTO log VALUES (8, '2010-06-04 03:00:00', 800);
INSERT INTO log VALUES (9, '2010-06-05 05:00:00', 900);
INSERT INTO log VALUES (10, '2010-06-05 03:00:00', 1000);
```

Result:

```
+------+---------------------+-------+
| id   | timestamp           | value |
+------+---------------------+-------+
|    1 | 2010-06-01 02:00:00 |   100 |
|    4 | 2010-06-02 02:00:00 |   400 |
|    6 | 2010-06-03 02:00:00 |   600 |
|    7 | 2010-06-04 02:00:00 |   700 |
|   10 | 2010-06-05 03:00:00 |  1000 |
+------+---------------------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: if you added a min(ID) to the derived table, and a ID clause to the join condition, you can work around the "assumes that your timestamps are unique" too.

Comment: @potatopeelings: I don't think it's that easy. `SELECT MIN(timestamp), MIN(id) FROM log GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)` on the above test case would return the last row as `2010-06-05 03:00:00 | 9`. If I were to add an ID clause to the JOIN condition, it would not match, because there is no row in the table with timestamp = `'2010-06-05 03:00:00' AND id = '9'`... (This is at least in MySQL).

Comment: oh yes, you're right. My bad. It'd have to be one more subquery or join to get the row with the lowest ID out of the ones with the lowest timestamps per day. Like you pointed out - not as easy as the MIN, MIN. Sorry!

Comment: @potatopeelings: No probs :) ... Yes I agree, that can be done with one additional subquery. If the OP requires that, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

mr vassallo, you're a rock star.

it worked great.  here is the postgres version of your SQL:

```
SELECT l.id, l.timestamp, l.value
FROM log l
INNER JOIN  (
             SELECT    MIN(timestamp) AS first_timestamp
             FROM      log
             GROUP BY  DATE(timestamp)
) sub_l ON (sub_l.first_timestamp = l.timestamp)
WHERE       l.timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL '30 DAY' ORDER BY l.timestamp;
```

there is no need to get the minimal ID because i cannot be guaranteed that the inserts will be in direct chronological order (the timestamp is not really the inserted time, but a timestamp residing within the data, and data packets can come out of order).

i really appreciate the help.  thank you for taking a look at this.

Comment: sorry, that should say 'SELECT MIN(timestamp) AS first_timestamp'

Comment: I'm glad this helped. And thanks for posting the Postgres version :) I've edited your answer to fix the `MIN(timestamp) AS ...` part as you suggested.